# Mandar un alert en FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Buen día, estoy comenzando a utilizar fullcalendar con js y también js, el calendar ya se muestra en mi pantalla pero no logro activar el Eventclick cunado hago click en algun recuadro de las fechas espero me puedan orientar gracias

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
        }, navLinks: true,
        businessHours: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        eventClick: function () {
            

            alert('Hola');
            
        },
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a mi propia pregunta y espero a alguien le sirva pienso fue un error muy basico

tenia que cambiar

```
     eventClick: function () {
   alert('Hola');
  },
```

por

```
 dateClick: function (info) {
       // alert('Hola');
    },
```

el problema era la función dateClick es para activar una acción al seleccionar una fecha del calendario